# Why is my raspbmc remote control keyboard very laggy?

Tags: raspbmc, keyboard, kodi, remote

During my first install of raspbmc, I could control text entry via my iPhone's [Official XMBC Remote](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Official_XBMC_Remote/iOS) app with no problems.

Later, I wiped and reinstalled raspbmc. Now, control via my keyboard is extremely laggy. Keys ae missed, sometimes they appear 10-20s later. Normal menu control via the remote is fine.

I've tried several skins but all have the same issue?

Any ideas? Anything I can do to help diagnose this further?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it has to do with the new XBMC build. The support for the native iOs app and android both decreased. It's even better to use the webinterface through safari.

or if your TV supports HDMI cec, use that remote.

Comment: hmm this post http://www.raspbmc.com/2012/10/raspbmc-512mb-support-more-improvements/ mentions the http depreciation, but then surely my remote should not work at all, rather than have just laggy input?

Comment: This old thread recommends a firmware update http://forum.stmlabs.com/showthread.php?tid=1771 but are you using RC5?

Comment: System info says 12.0-alpha7 at the moment.

Comment: Whoops -- followed that stmlabs thread and now I have a bricked pi! Lucky I backed up!